# Preciso de um de um programa que análise uma série de números com com três cores e preciso que me dê a porcentagem dos números conforme as cores

Tags: php

O programa que eu preciso consiste em analisar uma série de números e o mesmo tem três cores eu preciso do percentual de cada número conforme suas cores